# Bound on an implicitly defined solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Consider an equation

$$ F(x,\alpha)=0  \quad(1)$$

and assume that the above equation has at least one solution for all $\alpha\in[0,1].$ Let $X(\alpha)\equiv\{x|F(x,\alpha)=0\}$.

Suppose that at $\alpha=0$ we have $x>b$ for all $x\in X(0)$; that is, every solution to (1) at $\alpha=0$ is strictly greater than $b$.

I am trying to prove the following claim.

**Claim:** Fix $\varepsilon>0$ (sufficiently small). There exists $\underline{\alpha}>0$ such that for all $\alpha<\underline{\alpha}$ we have   $x\in X(\alpha)$ implies $x>b-\varepsilon$.

---

**My attempt:**

Using Taylor theorem we have
$$ F(x_1,\alpha_1)=F(x_0,\alpha_0)+F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})(x_1-x_0)+F_{\alpha}(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})(\alpha_1-\alpha_0),$$

where $\bar{x}\in(x_0,x_1)$ and $\bar{\alpha}\in(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$. Setting $x_1=x(\alpha_1)$, $x_0=x(\alpha_0)$, and $\alpha_0=0$ in the above equation, we obtain

$$ 0 = F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})(x(\alpha_1)-x(0))+F_{\alpha}(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})\alpha_1 $$

Rearranging and using the fact that $x(0)>b$ we obtain

$$ F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})x(\alpha_1) = F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})x(0) - F_{\alpha}(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})\alpha_1 $$

Assuming that $F_x$ is bounded away from $0$, divide both sides by  $F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})$ and using the fact that $x(0)>b$ to obtain

$$x(\alpha_1) > b - \frac{F_a(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})}{F_x(\bar{x},\bar{\alpha})}a $$

The claim then follows as long as derivatives are uniformly bounded.

---

Is the above argument correct? Can we drop some of the assumptions on the derivatives?